# Can't get custom font to load in iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, custom-font

I know this question has been asked before, but so far have not found an answer to my problem. I am trying to use a custom font (Rockwell) in my app, but can't get it to load in.

I have used the correct name from Font Book, which is just "Rockwell". I've added the file to the project, and its target is the project. I've added the file to the plist, and also to the bundle resources.

I'm using the following code to set the font of a label, with no luck.

```
UIFont *customFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Rockwell" size:18.0];
[self._textView setFont:customFont];
```

It also doesn't appear when I run something like:

```
NSLog(@"Available fonts: %@", [UIFont familyNames]);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What value did you set in your plist?  What is the file's name actual name (e.g., Rockwell.ttf)?

Comment: Well, I downloaded another .ttf file from a different source and it worked. I'm not sure why, as I could preview both files and they looked identical. Thanks for your help, guys. I'll post the answer after 8 hours or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloaded .ttf file from a different source, and now it works.